# d3.js: legends with dynamic element width

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to replace a d3 legend drawing function which used manual creation and placement of the legend elements to one using `.data()`.

I was able to get everything working, except one thing: with manually looping through the data array, I was able to ensure equal spacing between the legend elements by using a `currentX` tracker variable. With `.data()` however, I can't reference the other elements, and have to use fixed-width boxes, which the designer hates (and me too).

Given the code below, how do I make the new code (top row) behave exactly like the old code (bottom row)?

(Please do not suggest that I use a legend library, there is lots of event-handling and more stuff in the "real" code upon which this testcase was extracted)

```js
var config = {
  circleYCenter: 170,
  circleXCenter: 150,
  legendMarginTop: 52,
  legendMarginInner: 18,
  legendDotHeight: 8,
  legendDotWidth: 16,
};
var colors = {
  'lightyellow': '#FEE284',
  'darkblue': '#2872A3',
  'dirtyorange': '#E68406',
};

function drawLegend(container, map) {
  var legendGroup = container.append("g").attr({
    "transform": "translate(0,50)",
    "class": "legendGroup"
  });

  //New code
  var elGroup = legendGroup.selectAll("g").data(map).enter().append("g").attr({
    transform: function(d, i) {
      return "translate(" + (i * 100) + ",0)"
    }
  });

  elGroup.append("text").text(function(d) {
    return d.label;
  }).attr({
    x: config.legendDotWidth + config.legendMarginInner
  });
  elGroup.append("rect").attr({
    x: 0,
    width: config.legendDotWidth,
    y: -5,
    height: config.legendDotHeight,
    "fill": function(d) {
      return d.color;
    }
  });


  //Old code
  var currentX = 0;
  map.forEach(function(el, key) {
    var elGroup = legendGroup.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + currentX + ",100)");
    elGroup.append("rect").attr({
      x: 0,
      width: config.legendDotWidth,
      y: -5,
      height: config.legendDotHeight,
      "fill": el.color
    });
    elGroup.append("text").attr({
      "x": (config.legendDotWidth + 10),
      "y": 0,
      "alignment-baseline": "middle"
    }).text(el.label);
    currentX += elGroup.node().getBBox().width + config.legendMarginInner;
  });
}

drawLegend(d3.select("svg"), [{
  label: "foo",
  color: colors.dirtyorange
}, {
  label: "Banana",
  color: colors.darkblue
}, {
  label: "baz",
  color: colors.lightyellow
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width=600 height=300></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make the group:

```
 var elGroup = legendGroup.selectAll("g").data(map).enter().append("g");
```

Append the `text` and `rect` DOM as you are doing:

```
  elGroup.append("text").text(function(d) {
    return d.label;
  }).attr({
    x: config.legendDotWidth + config.legendMarginInner
  });

  elGroup.append("rect").attr({
    x: 0,
    width: config.legendDotWidth,
    y: -5,
    height: config.legendDotHeight,
    "fill": function(d) {
      return d.color;
    }
  });
```

Now add the translate to the group using the bbox of the group.

```
var currentX = 0;   
elGroup.attr({
    transform: function(d, i) {
            var ret = "translate(" + currentX + ",0)"
            currentX += this.getBBox().width + config.legendMarginInner;
      return ret;
    }
  });
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oq0cb5d5/)

Comment: @Cyril, could you please look into this issue https://jsfiddle.net/praveenuics/k1xssj9h/, Its about the legends, I will be using multiline chart where there are about 20 trend line where i need to show legends(20 in this case), all the legends are stacked next to each other untill it reaches end but i need them with in the svg box/scroll will also work, any help is much appreciated.